# pandas.cut() with NA values causing "boolean value of NA is ambiguous"

Tags: python, pandas

I would like to understand why this code does raise an `TypeError`.

```
import pandas
pandas.cut(x=[1, 2, pandas.NA, 4, 5, 6, 7], bins=3)
```

The full error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/user/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/core/reshape/tile.py", line 293, in cut
    fac, bins = _bins_to_cuts(
  File "/home/user/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/core/reshape/tile.py", line 428, in _bins_to_cuts
    ids = ensure_platform_int(bins.searchsorted(x, side=side))
  File "pandas/_libs/missing.pyx", line 382, in pandas._libs.missing.NAType.__bool__
TypeError: boolean value of NA is ambiguous
```

Of course the values containing missing (pandas.NA) values, too. But looking [into the to docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.cut.html) in the section *Notes*.

> Any NA values will be NA in the result. Out of bounds values will be
> NA in the resulting Series or Categorical object.

In my understanding of the docs this shouldn't throw an error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like `pd.cut` doesn't behave consistently when it hits the (relatively new) `pd.NA` value, [and it's not the only one](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/28095).

Please take some time to report it and relate it to the main issue.

In the mean time you can work around it wrapping the values in an `IntegerArray` which allow null values for integer types:

```py
# Using IntegerArray
In [1]: import pandas as pd

In [2]: pd.cut(x=pd.array([1, 2, pd.NA, 4, 5, 6, 7]), bins=3)
Out[2]:
[(0.994, 3.0], (0.994, 3.0], NaN, (3.0, 5.0], (3.0, 5.0], (5.0, 7.0], (5.0, 7.0]]
Categories (3, interval[float64, right]): [(0.994, 3.0] < (3.0, 5.0] < (5.0, 7.0]]
```

Or if you don't like using an experimental API you can use `np.array`, although this will change the dtype to float:

```py
In [1]: import pandas as pd

In [2]: import numpy as np

In [3]: pd.cut(x=np.array([1, 2, np.nan, 4, 5, 6, 7]), bins=3)
Out[3]:
[(0.994, 3.0], (0.994, 3.0], NaN, (3.0, 5.0], (3.0, 5.0], (5.0, 7.0], (5.0, 7.0]]
Categories (3, interval[float64, right]): [(0.994, 3.0] < (3.0, 5.0] < (5.0, 7.0]]
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

### *... to understand why this code does raise `TypeError`*

It's in nature of `pd.NA` value (https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/1.0.0/user_guide/missing_data.html).

> Experimental NA scalar to denote missing values
>
> **Warning** Experimental: the behaviour of `pd.NA` can still change without warning.

> ...
> In general, missing values propagate in operations involving `pd.NA`.
> When one of the operands is unknown, the outcome of the operation is
> also unknown.

> ...
> In equality and comparison operations, `pd.NA` also propagates.

> ...
> Since the actual value of an NA is unknown, it is ambiguous to convert
> NA to a boolean value. The following raises an error: `TypeError: boolean value of NA is ambiguous`

`pd.cut` uses `np.searchsorted` under the hood in it's internal `_bins_to_cuts` function which is in your case fails on line `ids = ensure_platform_int(bins.searchsorted(x, side=side))` where `x` is one of the *bins* criteria (marker).

Then, diving into `np.searchsorted`: it internally does comparison operations like `a[i-1] < v <= a[i]`/`a[i-1] <= v < a[i]` to find the insertion indices.

So with your input list `[1, 2, pd.NA, 4, 5, 6, 7]` any comparison like `<value> <= pd.NA` will give `pd.NA` instead of logical value (`True/False`) ... and that's indeed ambiguous and fails with respective error.

```
In [372]: 1 <= pd.NA
Out[372]: <NA>
```